# Bash: initialising an array arr=(), throws error in GitLab CI, expected }

Tags: bash, syntax, gitlab-ci

### Context

While running a test, which imports many scripts, an error is thrown in the script below. In particular, an array initialization: `arr=()` in Bash leads to an error on GitLab CI (in Alpine docker), whereas it runs fine (no errors), when running on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

### Code

In particular, the error is thrown on the following bit of Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Structure:github_status
github_repo_exists_locally(){
    github_repo="$1"
    if test -d "$MIRROR_LOCATION/GitHub/$github_repo"; then
        echo "FOUND"
    else
        echo "NOTFOUND"
    fi
}
 
get_git_branches() {
    local -n arr=$1             # use nameref for indirection
    local company=$2
    local git_repository=$3
    arr=() # innitialise array with branches
    
    local theoutput=$(cd "$MIRROR_LOCATION/$company/$git_repository" && git branch --all)
    
    
    # Parse branches from branch list response
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        number_of_lines=$(echo "$theoutput" | wc -l)
        if [ "$number_of_lines" -eq 1 ]; then
            arr+=("${line:2}")
        # Only parse remote branches.
        elif [ "${line:0:17}" == "  remotes/origin/" ]; then
            
            # Remove the substring that identifies a remote branch to get the actual branch name up to the first space.
            # Assumes branch names can't contain spaces
            branch=$(get_rhs_of_line_till_character "${line:17}" " ")
            
            # Filter out the HEAD branch duplicate, by filtering on a substring that indicates the duplicate.
            if [ "${branch:0:10}" != "-> origin/" ]; then
                
                # Filter out git theoutput artifacts of that do not start with a letter or number.
                # Assumes branch names always start with a letter or number.
                # TODO: make this check silent.
                if grep '^[-0-9a-zA-Z]*$' <<<"${branch:0:1}" ;then 
                    
                    # Append the branch name to the array of branches
                    #echo "branch=$branch"
                    arr+=("$branch")
                fi          
            fi
        fi
    # List branches and feed them into a line by line parser
    done <<< "$theoutput"
}
```

### Error message

> ./test.sh: src/helper/GitHub/helper_github_status.sh: line 56: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "}")
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2

### .GitLab-CI.yml

Several issues mentioned in the comments led to errors, because the docker ran an Alpine environment instead of Ubuntu. A combination of the comments led to a valid build status for a trivial `bats` repository, I am now testing it on the code in the question:

```yaml
unit_test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - apk update && apk add bash
        - apk add git # Default docker image uses Alpine iso Ubuntu, hence apk.
        - chmod +x *.sh
        - ./install-bats-libs.sh
        - bash ./test.sh
```

### Notes

- I suspect it may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70006905/7437143) question, yet I do not yet know how.
- I manually verified that there is not an open { bracket that is lingering/unclosed, hence, I was wondering:

### Question

*Why does this error occur, and can I resolve it by changing the array declaration?*

Comment: *`bit of Bash script`* is a bit misleading when there's ~90 lines of code to debug; consider adding `set -x` at the top of the script to enable debug mode, run the script, review the debug output; if you're still unsure of the issue then update the question with the lines of code causing the issue and the related debug output

Comment: Alpine doesn't ship with bash. Did you `apk add` it in your Dockerfile? Also, if you invoke the script like `sh script.sh`, then you need to explicitly invoke it like `bash script.sh`. In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` symlinks to bash

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you, I've removed unused code, and will apply the `set -x` to review the debug output.

Comment: @glennjackman thank you, I was not aware alpine does not ship with bash, mostly because it seemed to run the bash without saying "bash is a problem". I will look at GitLab yaml examples to see how to `apk add bash` to the docker container, or otherwise find a docker container that supports `apt` (and bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors were indeed caused by the docker running an Alpine environment instead of Ubuntu. A combination of the comments led to the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which resulted in a `passing` build status for the code above:

```yaml
unit_test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - apk update && apk add bash
        - apk add git # Default docker image uses Alpine iso Ubuntu, hence apk.
        - chmod +x *.sh
        - ./install-bats-libs.sh
        - bash ./test.sh
```